# squid authentication with win2008

Tags: proxy, squid

sir,i intalled asquid server in linux redhat5..i need to authenitcate the users from my acivre directory in windos 2008.but its repaetedly prompting for username and password and finally tels accec denied.i configuredthrough ntlm auth in squid..pls helpme anyone

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any information about your setup?

I myself, followed the following [information](http://www.linux-faqs.com/faq/squid-faq/FAQ-23.php) to setup a working ntlm authentication. Against win 2003 but I think it's pretty mucht the same process.

did you test the rpc with wbinfo -t ? Did the samba/winbind join to the 2008 domain correctly?

the cache.log in squid also helps a lot in troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

Search the site and you will find lots of good material, like this one: [getting-squid-to-authenticate-with-kerberos-and-windows-2008-2003-7-xp](https://serverfault.com/questions/66556/getting-squid-to-authenticate-with-kerberos-and-windows-2008-2003-7-xp)