# Failure to create keytab file using msktutil on Centos to W2K8

Tags: windows-server-2008, squid, kerberos

I'm trying to setup a centos 5.5 squid server to authenticate against a windows 2008 DC.
I have followed the tutorial:
[Getting Squid to authenticate with kerberos and Windows 2008/2003/7/XP](https://serverfault.com/questions/66556/getting-squid-to-authenticate-with-kerberos-and-windows-2008-2003-7-xp)
However I have run into an issue.
When I run the command: (Obviously changed for my enviroment)

```
# msktutil -c -b "CN=COMPUTERS" -s HTTP/centos.dom.local -h centos.dom.local -k /etc/HTTP.keytab --computer-name centos-http --upn HTTP/centos.dom.local --server server.dom.local --verbose --enctypes 28
```

I get the following error (The whole message is too long to post here):

```
Error: Unable to set machine password for centos: (3) Authentication error
Error: set_password failed
```

kinit works fine and the computer is added to the DC under COMPUTERS and SRV records created except no keytab is created.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, I had several problems with the red hat 5.3, lots of flashing, sometimes works and sometimes not.

Get download packet bin msktutil in http://packages.sw.be/msktutil/ , I had better results, but unsatisfactory.

I did a test in debian lenny and the results were more positive.